# Derivatives as "dynamical variables of the theory"?

Tags: field-theory, string-theory, supersymmetry, ads-cft, supergravity

This question will probably sounds very broad.

So, I work with classical general relativity, a bit of field theory and semiclassical gravity. I have a friend, though, that works with things like supersymmetry, supergravity and AdS/CFT.

He keeps saying that in some theories (using vielbeins) the derivatives that appears in lagrangians become "dynamical" rather than "static". Also, he stress that working with vielbeins is better than classical pseudo-Riemannian geometry.

I mean, I know that it is possible to introduce structures like Frame bundles and reformulate general relativity using Einstein-Cartan formalism; it is "cleaner", indeed. But I didn't grasp the point on turning derivatives 'dynamical".

So I would like to ask: **what does it mean a derivative becomes a "dynamical variable" of the theory?** (would be nice if you show some explicit math)

Comment: Perhaps he means that the spin connection becomes a dynamical field in its own right whereas previously (without torsion), the spin connection is related to the derivative of the vielbein. So in this sense, the derivate of the vielbein is a separate dynamical field. Can't think of anything else apart from this. It is not a phrase I'm familiar with (and is perhaps non-standard). You should ask your friend to clarify what that means.